# SessionID changes with each HTTP request

Tags: php, angularjs, http, session, reactjs

I've just started using the `fetch` API to send my data as ReactJS recommends. Prior to this, to send API requests to my server I used AngularJS. I am currently encountering the most annoying bug, sending HTTP requests fails to load the correct session.

Firstly, my web application uses a PHP API to expose itself and is (basically for now) a bunch of `.php` files to get parts of the app. One of them is `authenticateUser.php` which authenticates and stores the session. However, I noticed that my HTTP requests with `fetch` weren't working as expected as other stuff like `getCurrentUser.php` returned `NotLoggedIn`, despite just authenticating. I thought it might have something to do with the sessions, so on `authenticateUser.php`, I set my `.php` file to output the current `session_id` after authenticating via.: (`echo array('session_id' => session_id());`

I have noticed that basically, when I myself load the url myself in the browser: `myapp.com/php/http/user/authenticateUser.php`, the `session_id` I get is completely different from the one I get when using `fetch`:

```
return fetch("/php/http/user/authenticateUser.php", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}).then(function(successResponse) {
    return successResponse.json();
}, function(errorResponse) {
    console.log(errorResponse);
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I checked further and thought maybe it was because `fetch` was querying `http` version of my site instead of the non-HTTP version of my site. So I changed the logic on `authenticateUser.php` such that if it detects a session existing, it prints out that `session_id`, else it creates and prints out the new one. Everytime I sent my HTTP request with `fetch` I got a different `session_id` meaning that my `session_id` was changing with each request. Here is the code I used:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json"); 
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
http_response_code(200);
echo json_encode(array('session_id' => session_id()),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Am I missing something completely different with `fetch` API, or headers? Or does anyone have any experience with this that could possibly enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that `fetch` by default does not send cookies, you need to specify it via:

`credentials: same-origin`